# Comportamento estranho pós condicional (Criando array)

Tags: php

Considerando que eu tenho estas classes auxiliares:

```
class HorasDisponiveis {
    public $diaSemana;
    public $horario;
    public $disponivel;
    public $confirmado;
    public $qtdDocas;
}

class FaixasDisponiveis {
    public $horaInicial;
    public $horaFinal;
    public $intervalo;
    public $livre;
    public $data;
    public $diaSemana;
}
```

Mais o código:

```
$faixasDisponiveis = [];

        foreach($horasDisponiveis as $item){
            if(!isset($horaInicial)) {
                $horaInicial = str_pad($item->horario->hour, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT) . ":" . str_pad($item->horario->minute, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
            }

            $horaFinal = str_pad($item->horario->hour, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT) . ":" . str_pad($item->horario->minute, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

            if($item->disponivel){
                $faixaDisponivel = new FaixasDisponiveis();
                $faixaDisponivel->horaInicial = $horaInicial;
                $faixaDisponivel->horaFinal = $horaFinal;
                $faixaDisponivel->diaSemana = $item->horario->dayOfWeek;
                $faixaDisponivel->data = $item->horario->year . "-" . $item->horario->month . "-" . $item->horario->day;
                array_push($faixasDisponiveis, $faixaDisponivel);
                unset($horaFinal);
                unset($horaInicial);
            }
        }
        return $faixasDisponiveis;
```

Eu tenho o seguinte resultado:

```
 "data": [
         {
             "horaInicial": [
                 "10",
                 "00"
             ],
             "horaFinal": "07:00",
             "intervalo": null,
             "livre": null,
             "data": "2019-5-16",
             "diaSemana": 4
         }, (...)
```

A minha dúvida é, porque ao inserir o condicionante de setado (isset), ele transforma a variável em um array? Perceba que a única diferença entre a variável $horaInicial e a $horaFinal é apenas verificando se ela está setada.

Dados ($horasDisponiveis)

```
"data": [
        {
            "diaSemana": 4,
            "horario": {
                "date": "2019-05-16 07:00:00.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "America/Sao_Paulo"
            },
            "disponivel": true,
            "confirmado": false,
            "qtdDocas": 2
        },
        {
            "diaSemana": 4,
            "horario": {
                "date": "2019-05-16 07:10:00.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "America/Sao_Paulo"
            },
            "disponivel": true,
            "confirmado": false,
            "qtdDocas": 2
        },
        {
            "diaSemana": 4,
            "horario": {
                "date": "2019-05-16 07:20:00.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "America/Sao_Paulo"
            },
            "disponivel": true,
            "confirmado": false,
            "qtdDocas": 2
        }(...)
```

Comment: Acredito que o problema não esteja voltado para `isset`, ele não manipula a variável, na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) não indica nada do tipo e fiz testes aqui e nada foi alterado. Faz um teste e coloca um isset na `$horaFinal` para verificar se existe alguma relação.

Comment: Você pode dar um exemplo de valores do seu array `$horasDisponiveis`? Não consegui reproduzir esse problema nos testes que fiz https://ideone.com/LJvB1Y.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e adicionei o valor.

Comment: Adicionando o isset no $horaFinal, o comportamento foi o mesmo, transformou em um array. Minha questão nem é o valor em sí, mas o motivo pelo qual está transformando a string em array, este é o ponto central.

Comment: Já identifiquei o erro. Em um trecho acima no código, existe dentro de outro foreach duas variáveis com o mesmo nome. Em minha ideia, estas variáveis ficariam dentro do escopo do foreach, o que não ocorre no php pelo visto. Setei ambas para null e o erro não ocorreu mais.

Comment: Tente acrescentar uma condição ao `if`: `if(!isset($horaInicial) or true)`. Se o erro desaparecer, o problema pode ser o formato da variável antes de passar pelo `if`